# What's my best option for creating animations with existing single view application code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I already have my app finished but i want to polish it with some nice animations. Nothing to crazy, I just need to loop through some sprites to make it look like a plant is growing. For obvious reasons, I don't want to try and work this into a cocos2d framework. I found a couple animation classed on the web, but the animation look crappy and unnatural. Any ideas as to how I can best achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView animations would be the easiest. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uiimageview-animation/